# Function with ordered arguments

Tags: z3

It seems that uninterpret functions treat arguments as unordered. 
For example,

```
(declare-fun Lturn (Int Int Int) Bool)
(assert (forall ((x Int) (y Int) (z Int)) 
                (not (= (Lturn x y z) (Lturn x z y)))))
(check-sat)
```

The result is UNSAT. 
The above code is available here: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/hkpwO

To overcome this situation, I tried using array:

```
(declare-fun Lturn ((Array Int Int)) Bool)
(assert (forall ((A1 (Array Int Int)) (A2 (Array Int Int))) 
                (=> (and (= (select A1 1) (select A2 1)) 
                         (= (select A1 2) (select A2 3)) 
                         (= (select A1 3) (select A2 2)))
                    (not (= (Lturn A1) (Lturn A2))))))
(check-sat)
```

The result is "unknown." 
The above code is available here: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/bdTL

Is there any method to let the Array version be SAT?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Function arguments are not unordered. Can you give a function `Lturn` that would make your assertion SAT? Here's a simpler case with just two arguments: http://rise4fun.com/Z3/Zsjs

For `x == 0 && y == 0 && z == 0` there is no function such that `f(x, y, z) != f(x, z, y)` because `f(0, 0, 0) != f(0, 0, 0)` is always false.